# npm run build sh: 1: next: Permission denied when I run docker compose build

Tags: npm, dockerfile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, react-typescript

I am trying to build a Docker image of a react typescript project (in WSL), but in the process I'm getting this error:
`

```
 => ERROR [x_site 7/7] RUN npm run build                                                                      2.6s
------
 > [x_site 7/7] RUN npm run build:
2.459
2.459 > x-site@0.1.0 build
2.459 > next build
2.459
2.465 sh: next: Permission denied
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:20-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app
ADD package.json package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

I've tried to run `npm run build`  since command line and get the same error, so I run `npm config set unsafe-perm true` but didn't works either.

Comment: how did u solve this?